# Loading external script with jinja2 template directive

Tags: python, templates, scripting, jinja2, external

I'm very new to jinja2 and the use of templates in general so I was wondering if there's an easy way to load an external javascript. I was thinking of using:

```html
{% block javascript %}
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

But I can't help to ask:

**Is there a way of loading this script directly from within a template directive?**

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have two choices here -- the first is the way you did it -- simply add the appropriate markup into a template (or a block if you want to be able to override it in templates which extend your first template.)

The second way is to use Jinja2's [`include`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/templates#include) function:

```html
{% block javascript %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        {% include "myscript.js" %}
    </script>
    <!-- The contents of myscript.js will be loaded inside the script tag -->
{% endblock %}
```

The advantage of using `include` is that Jinja2 will process your javascript before including it -- which means you can have variables in your javascript that change depending on the state of your program.

The disadvantage of using `include` in this manner is the same -- your `.js` file will be run through Jinja2 before being sent out -- if you are not using dynamic content you will just be processing the file unnecessarily for every request -- and if you are using a javascript templating library with Jinja2 syntax then trouble is likely.

Comment: So this will basically include everything inside the file myscript.js between those tags, I'm I right? Any reason I could not use this to include a text file or something else?

Comment: @kirbuchi -- yes, exactly.  The same trade-offs apply.

Comment: Sean, thanks for this. Can you include from the static folder, or the include only works from the templates folder? I am asking this, because the myscript.js should be in static folder.

Comment: @anvd did you get an answer for this?

Comment: @pee2pee I don't find a way. I need to load it from templates.

Comment: Damn - thanks for replying

Answer (score 4):

This question is quite old, but there is another way of doing it that might be interesting as well. I found it while working with *Jinja2* and *flask*.

I used the `url_for()` and it works fine:

```html
{% block javascript %}
    <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='myscript.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

And I have my `myscript.js` in my static folder. Specified in Jinja2 environment, or by default in flask.

Comment: The code should include `"` before `{{` and after `}}`, i.e. `src="{{ url_for('static',filename='myscript.js') }}"`, otherwise it is not valid HTML

Comment: Thanks, nice catch ;)