# Flask - Different Javascript file for each template

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I'm working on an application built with flask and using templates. I have a layout.html file with head tags and js/css links which I'm importing on each page using:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {# My content #}
{% endblock content %}
```

This works but I now need to link to other JS files only for specific html files and wondering what is the correct way of doing it using flask.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply include your `<script>` tags in the HTML file where you need them. This way, the javascript will be imported only when that specific page is loaded.

An example is:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
   {# My content #}
{% endblock content %}
{% block scripts %}
  <script scr="..."></script>
{% endblock scripts %}
```

Comment: This worked for me - to be explicit, in the `layout.html`, add `{% block scripts %} // {% endblock %}` after the `</body>` (or wherever you want the scripts to load.)

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, you want some of your `HTML` pages to have a link to JavaScript code.
To achieve this just add the `<script>` tag in that particular `HTML` page as follows:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='JS/some_file.js') }}"></script>
```

where-
JavaScript file is kept at: `static`->`JS`->`some_file.js`

Answer (score 0):

```
{% block javascript %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    {% include "some-js-file.js" %}
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Create a code block like the block above.

For completeness, you can also reference this SO question: [Loading external script with jinja2 template directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412275/loading-external-script-with-jinja2-template-directive)

Answer (score 0):

You can have all the unique Javascript tags in the `layout.html` file then for each [endpoint](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.endpoint) use `if else` statements to render the tag you want for each page. The endpoint is simply the name of the view function.

```
{% if request.endpoint == 'index' %}
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='JS/file.js') }}"></script>
{% elif request.endpoint == 'another-endpoint' %}
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='JS/some_other_file.js') }}"></script>
```